# Edit and save changes in file with powershell script

Tags: powershell

please tel me how to edit variable content in xml file with powershell script.

```
<application>
<name>My Application</name>
<platforms>
    <platform>android</platform>
    <icon gap:density="ld" src="/icon-1.png" />
    <icon gap:density="md" src="/icon-2.png" />
</platforms>
</application>
```

i tried this but, it's not what i want, i want to edit based on the name of the variable: name, platform... but i dont know how in powershell

```
$editfiles=get-childitem . *.xml -rec
foreach ($file in $editfiles)
{
(get-content $file.pspath) | 
foreach-object {$_ -replace "My Application", "My New App"} | set-content $file.pspath }
```

Tks
Many tks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? Show some effort here - don't just come in & ask Stack Overflow to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to edit XML documents using an XML Api rather than text search/replace.  Try this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content foo.xml
$xml.application.name = "new name"
$xml.Save("$pwd\foo.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newitem = $xml.CreateElement("Value")
$newitem.set_InnerXML("111")            
$xml.Items.ReplaceChild($newitem, $_)
```

something like this i think.. i didn't try it so i could be off track

Answer (score 0):

Please use Keith Hill's answer, I'm only leaving mine here for reference. He's right, it's better to modify it through an XML API. I never use XML, I'm not familiar with it, so I didn't even think of it.

I gotta ask, did you try anything to do this? Did you look for an answer? This is pretty basic stuff that just a minute or two on Google probably would have gotten you an answer for.

```
(Get-Content "C:\Source\SomeFile.XML") -replace "My Application","Shiny New App"|Set-Content "C:\Source\SomeFile.XML"
```

Or if you wanted to change something less specific, such as the word "android" for the platform tag you could just include the tags to make sure it gets the right thing. (some shorthand used in this example)

```
(GC "C:\Source\SomeFile.XML") -replace "<platform>android</platform>","<platform>tacos</platform>"|SC "C:\Source\SomeFile.XML"
```

Seriously though, at least try and help yourself before coming and asking to be spoon-fed answers. I just hit up Google and searched for "powershell replace text in file" and the very first link would have given you the answer.

Edit:
Without knowing what you are looking for and going based solely off tags you will need to perform a RegEx (Regular Expression) search.

```
(GC "C:\Source\SomeFile.XML") -replace "(?<=`<platform`>).*?(?=`</platform`>)", 'New Platform'
```

That will pull the content of the file, look for any length of text that is preceded with  and followed by  and replace that text with 'New Platform'. Note that the Greater Than and Less Than symbols are escaped with a grave character (to the left of the 1, and above the Tab on your keyboard). Here's a breakdown of the RegEx:
`(?<=<platform>)` Checks that immediately preceding the string that we're looking for is the string `<platform>`. This will not be replaced, it just makes sure we have the right starting point.
`.*?` searches for any number of characters except a new line, and accepts the possibility that it may be blank. This is our match that will be replaced.
`(?=</platform>)` Checks that immediately following the string it just found should be the string `</platform>`. This will not be replaced, it just makes sure our match ends at the correct place.

Comment: the problem here is that i want to edit what is between tags without knowing it, just based on the name of the tage, is that possible with powershell? for example if i want to edit android i want just too specify that i want to edit platform. tks